# Output buffering, hierarchical?

Tags: php, apache, output-buffering

Output buffering in PHP is fun. It simplifies many things. I use ob_start() at the top of the script and ob_get_clean() (or any other function) at the bottom.

Between those two calls is it possible to call those functions again, without interfering the parent calls.

Is this type of code valid ? (it works fine, but...) Is this a good habit ?

```
<?php

ob_start(); //NOTICE !!!

echo '<p>echos of the top of the script</p>';
echo GetSomeOtherData(true);
echo '<p>echos after GetSomeOtherData()</p>';

$data = ob_get_clean(); //NOTICE !!!
echo $data;

//just a function to return something, with the help of output buffering
function GetSomeOtherData($toReturn)
{

    ob_start();     //NOTICE !!!
    echo '<p>This has been rendered inside a function</p>';
    $function_data = ob_get_clean();    //NOTICE !!!

    if($toReturn===true)
    {
        return $function_data;
    }
    else
    {
        //may be an error | return something else
        return '<p>An Error</p>';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [`ob_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) manual:

> Output buffers are stackable, that is, you may call ob_start() while
>   another ob_start() is active. Just make sure that you call
>   ob_end_flush() the appropriate number of times. If multiple output
>   callback functions are active, output is being filtered sequentially
>   through each of them in nesting order.

So it is perfectly valid to assume that an `ob_end/get` will end/return the matching `ob_start` e.g.:

```
ob_start();
  echo "<div class=outer>";
  ob_start();
    echo "<div class=inner></div>";
  $inner = ob_get_clean(); // <div class=inner></div>
  echo "</div>";
$outer = ob_get_clean();     // <div class=outer></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In all honesty, I don't see any problem with that. Every call to ob_start() is matched by an ob_get_clean() call, so the use of such functions is completely transparent to the "parent" ob_start(). It would be a horrible habit if pairs (of calls to ob_start() and ob_get_clean()) didn't match -- but as long as they do, it shouldn't (and won't) cause you any trouble.